# Installing the SQLite3 gem on Windows: sqlite.h is found, sqlite itself is not

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I've installed Ruby 2.1 using the RubyInstaller, and I've set up the devkit, which is in my PATH. Other gems with native extensions, like `json`, work totally fine, and compile normally.

I downloaded the SQLite amalgamation and source code, put it in `c:\sqlite3`, and added that to my PATH. I now attempt to run `gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby -- --with-sqlite3-dir=C:/sqlite3 --with-sqlite3-include=C:/sqlite3`. This fails with the error

```
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... no
sqlite3 is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ first.
```

*** extconf.rb failed ***

`sqlite3.exe` is downloaded and in my PATH, and I can use SQLite databases from the command prompt just fine. I don't know what else the gem could possibly want from me -- SQLite3.h is there, SQLite is there, it works. No instructions and no StackOverflow posts mention this error, anything else I could do, or extra steps.

Comment: I also had this problem a while ago and failed to solve it after some hours of research. I gave up and used Ruby 1.9.3 instead and it worked. I was just doing this to follow a tutorial; it wasn't for production use.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same problem and was able to solve it with the following gem install:

```
gem i sqlite3 --platform=ruby -- --with-sqlite3-dir=C:/Tools/sqlite --with-sqlite3-include=C:/Tools/sqlite --with-sqlite3-lib=C:/Tools/sqlite
```

I had to add all three of the switches to get it to work. I tried with just

```
--with-sqlite3-dir=C:/Tools/sqlite
```

...and then with

```
--with-sqlite3-dir=C:/Tools/sqlite --with-sqlite-include=C:/Tools/sqlite
```

but those didn't work. Adding the

```
--with-sqlite3-lib=C:/Tools/sqlite
```

...is what did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to install sqlite3 gem on windows with this command:

```
gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

Comment: When I installed it, it said to type "gem install sqlite3" instead because sqlite3-ruby was deprecated or something. It worked for me though.